# Query childrens children in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Country -> State -> Suburb

On the state page I am pulling through all the children with:

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
```

Using the same at the top level only returns state level information (based on the parent id relationship). Is there an easy way to select the next level down as well, all children of the current id and their children as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom query for this. Try:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $child_pages = get_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID
    ) );
?>
```

This will get all descendants of the current page.